# MySQL cannot start. [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql

My MySQL server has not started. I've used this setting before, but today it does not work.

I have a local configuration with Laragon (WAMP). It smells like it's about some corrupted file, but I can not figure out how to fix it.

I have MySQL running on port 3306. I made a `netstat -an` command and there is no process on port 3306.

Here is the MySQL log:

```
2019-06-30T21:11:11.193517Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2019-06-30T21:11:11.194520Z 0 [Note] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as process 19280 ...
2019-06-30T21:11:21.270388Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2019-06-30T21:11:21.271388Z 0 [Note] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as process 9556 ...
2019-06-30T21:11:21.329394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-06-30T21:11:21.332393Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-06-30T21:11:21.333392Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-06-30T21:11:21.336389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-06-30T21:11:21.339395Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-06-30T21:11:21.341392Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-06-30T21:11:21.352391Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-06-30T21:11:21.373417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-30T21:11:21.422637Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.310467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-06-30T21:11:26.314466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-30T21:11:26.362467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.376466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.378465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.381466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-06-30T21:11:26.434466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5053ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2019-06-30T21:11:26.435467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.19 started; log sequence number 6109749964
2019-06-30T21:11:26.443470Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.443470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\laragon\data\mysql\mysql\ib_buffer_pool
2019-06-30T21:11:26.474469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190630 22:11:26
2019-06-30T21:11:26.475467Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-06-30T21:11:26.482467Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2019-06-30T21:11:26.485469Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.488467Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2019-06-30T21:11:26.490468Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.493468Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2019-06-30T21:11:26.497468Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-06-30T21:11:26.503471Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-06-30T21:11:26.504471Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-06-30T21:11:26.506466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.509469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.511468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.513468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.515467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.518470Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.520476Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.522468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.524466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.527467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.531465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.534469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.537467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.539465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.541466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.544472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.547469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.549468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.551465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.553466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.554466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.556466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.558465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.560468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.562466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.564465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.566465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.568465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.570465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.572466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.573466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.575466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.577467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.579465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.580465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.582467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.584466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.585465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-06-30T21:11:26.587468Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-06-30T21:11:26.589468Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-06-30T21:11:26.695999Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to C:\laragon\data\mysql\mysql\ib_buffer_pool
2019-06-30T21:11:26.708998Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190630 22:11:26
2019-06-30T21:11:27.836519Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6109749983
2019-06-30T21:11:27.839546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-06-30T21:11:27.841544Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-06-30T21:11:27.842545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-06-30T21:11:27.843545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-06-30T21:11:27.845545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-06-30T21:11:27.847529Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-06-30T21:11:27.865520Z 0 [Note] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, did you mean by “I've used this setting before, but today it does not work.”?

Comment: It is not a fresh install. I ran this local server before, with the same configuration (I did not changed it).

Just for information, I solved it. It was Windows firewall, that blocked mysqld when I put Laragon to start when Windows start.

Note: I didn't find how to close this question, or mark as solved. So, I write an answer.

Comment: (1) Yes, I saw your answer.  So I guess you’re saying that you had this working *sooo looong ago* that you changed the firewall and forgot about it?  (2) To the left of your answer, you should see a couple of voting buttons; triangles (one pointing up and one pointing down).  Below them you should see a checkmark.  If you click that, it marks the answer as ‘‘accepted’’, which is as close as we come to marking questions as ‘‘solved’’.  Because you’re a new user, and you answered your own question, you may need to wait a while before you can click the checkmark — maybe as much as 48 hours.

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott. 
Sorry, I meant that I changed Laragon to run when Windows starts, a day before. But I didn't figure out that it might cause problems with firewall. 
Now, I think that may be Windows detected a process starting for the system user (without my user logon), and that is the cause of changing firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a thousand times:
"When some service does not work, first look at the firewall"

How much time lost looking solution!
I rebooted my computer and it appeared to me a message of Windows warning that it had blocked the mysqld.

That's because the last time I work with local sites, I configured Laragon to start every time Windows starts. It was enough for the Windows firewall to start blocking.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 version of mysql in your system please change the port of the newer version of mysql or stop before version service on your system to release port number 3306.